# Changing dataframe columns (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to change the columns of a dataframe to no avail.

Here is the dataframe:

```
>>> file = open("data.csv", "r")
>>> data = pd.DataFrame(file)
>>> print(data)
                                                   0
0   date,1. open,2. high,3. low,4. close,5. volume\n
1  2020-01-14,316.7,317.57,312.17,312.68,40653457...
2  2020-01-15,311.85,315.5,309.55,311.34,30480882...
3  2020-01-16,313.59,315.7,312.09,315.24,27207254...
```

Here is the data.rename function to change the column names as documented - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

```
#Trying to change the columns with a dict
>>> data.rename(columns={"date": "date", "1. open": "open", "2. high": "high", "3. low": "low", "5. volume": "volume"})
                                                   0
0   date,1. open,2. high,3. low,4. close,5. volume\n
1  2020-01-14,316.7,317.57,312.17,312.68,40653457...
2  2020-01-15,311.85,315.5,309.55,311.34,30480882...
3  2020-01-16,313.59,315.7,312.09,315.24,27207254...
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Updating:
Thanks for all the responses.

I explicitly defined the column that I wanted to see and it all worked perfected.

```
>>> df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']
>>> print (df)
         col1    col2    col3    col4    col5        col6
0  2020-01-14  316.70  317.57  312.17  312.68  40653457.0
1  2020-01-15  311.85  315.50  309.55  311.34  30480882.0
2  2020-01-16  313.59  315.70  312.09  315.24  27207254.0
```

Comment: Read your dataframe with `pandas.read_csv`. Currently you  are producing a single column with the name `0`.

Comment: what does `data = pd.read_csv()` give you?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, use `pd.read_csv("data.csv", columns=['col1', 'col2',...])` when reading a csv to a `DataFrame`.

Also, here's an easy way to change `DataFrame` column names:

```py
df.columns = ['col_name1', 'col_name2', ...]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, bug. New tool in my arsenal!

Comment: When I use this within the interpreter, it worked perfectly. But when I use it within data.py package by explicitly defining the columns, the print is still invoking the old attributes. 

df = data
df.column = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
print(df)

And I still got this:
 df.column = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
             1. open   2. high    3. low  4. close   5. volume
date                                                          
2020-01-14  163.3900  163.6000  161.7200    162.13  23500783.0

Comment: Found my typo in df.columns. Thank you again, bug.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open the file when using pandas;

```
data = pandas.read_csv('path_to/your_file.csv')
```

I always add `inplace=True` to the rename function.

But if you just want to remove the numbers from the column names, you could as well do this;

```
data.columns = [col.split()[1] for col in data.columns]
```

Comment: Thank you, Sy. This one is very much for the keep. The only problem with my columns is that one of them has only index [0], so the split iterate doesn't work. I could use a 'While True' statement to check if there is a split applicable to each column.

Answer (score 0):

you can explicitly specify the new column names(Apart from the ones which are already there in the file) while reading the file as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', columns=['new_col1', 'new_col2', ...])
```

But if you won't add the columns attribute then bydefault the column names mentioned in the csv file will be taken by the dataframe.

Comment: This is perfect! I didn't realize that I could explicitly define how I want the columns. This solves the problem beautifully! Thank you very much, Vaibhav.